# Model of affine space whose saturation is projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, model-theory, projective-space, affine-schemes

In model theory, the concept of a saturated model can be thought of as a process of adjoining `limit points'. For example a saturated model of $\mathbb Q$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ is a certain linear order extending $\mathbb R$; containing all the dedekind cuts which are classically thought of as filling in the 'holes' in $\mathbb Q$.

Is there a worked out reasonable context, in which we can think of projective space $\mathbb P^k_n$ as a "saturated" model of affine space $\mathbb A^n_k$, in the sense of adding in the points of infinity as limit points?

I hope that such a model would capture $\mathbb P^k_n$ as a algebro-geometric object, perhaps capitalizing on the fact that over an algebraically closed field $k$, the type space $S_n(L)$ for a field $L\subset k$ is topologically the same as $\mathbb A^n_L$ except that the principal closed sets $V(I)$ for an ideal $I\subset L[x_1,...,x_n]$ are both open as well as closed.

Comment: Hi Victor. I just have a little nit-picky thing.  $\mathbb{R}$ is a super weird example of a linear order. In some sense, it isn't not the correct model-theoretic completion of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is because it does not realized all the types over the rationals. You need to go to the hyper-reals.

Comment: I am aware of this problem, hence my phrasing that a saturated model is a certain linear order "extending" $\mathbb R$. Perhaps I have been sloppy, and really only want $\mathbb P^n_k$ to be contained in a saturation of affine space.

Comment: Oops. I must have misread. My apologies. I will leave my old answer as a comment then: I think I have some bad news as well. If your language is rich enough to talk about points and lines, this can never be the case. Since in projective space, we can say that every two lines meet at a single point. The same is not true for affine space. Therefore, our two structure are not elementarily equivalent. In particular, $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ cannot be a saturated model of $Th_{\mathcal{L}}(\mathbb{A}_{k}^n)$.